# How to get the number of rows affected, if it hits sql exception while running the sql script in c#

Tags: c#, sql, exception, executenonquery

I need to get the number of rows affected if `ExecuteNonQuery()` hits the `SqlException`. I'm able to see the Number of affected rows while debugging in c#, but unable to get that, like-

> cmd.InternalRecordsAffected
>
> cmd._rowsAffected

I have already tried using below code along with PRINT statement, but it didn't work with my case:

```
conn.InfoMessage += delegate (object sender, SqlInfoMessageEventArgs e)
{
     sqlMessage += "\n" + e.Message;
};
```

Our application is running the sql scripts using c#. Below is the sample code:

```
int rowsAffected = -1;

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    if (conn != null && conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        conn.Open();
    }
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(strFilePath);
        string sqlQuery = reader.ReadToEnd();
        cmd.CommandText = sqlQuery;
        try
        {
            rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            //How to get the number of rows affected here?
        }
        if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

In exception, getting rowsAffected as -1, but needs the actual count.

Comment: If you use transactions then it's 0 affected rows.

Comment: Also, when a query fails, how should it know how many rows it yielded?

Comment: What you want to do with the rowsAffected when the code enters the exception? Is this an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: As I mentioned in the description, we are running sql scripts via c#, I need to log how many records affected.

Comment: So your file contains an undefined number of sql statements separated by a semicolons and you want to know at which point your script contains a error?

Comment: If I execute same script on database which consists suppose 3 queries and for first query it fails, it still executes remaining two queries which is fine. So I want to know the number of records affected by the 2nd and 3rd queries, even if it hits exception for 1st one in c#. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: That is not how it works. Split your statements and execute them separately.

Comment: Did you try if, after a failing statement, the following ones are still executed when you use C# code and the ADO.NET libraries? It is not the same thing, in code you don't have an IDE like Sql Server Management Studio that handles the exceptions and continue

Comment: @Patrick: That's not possible as we are having too many script files containing multiple sql statements which need to be run via c# application.

Comment: You can tell as much as you want that "it is not possible", but it is not possible to do that using ADO.NET. So you have two options: you abandon ADO.NET or your split the statements.

Comment: @Steve: Yes, I have just confirmed again and it's executing the 2nd and 3rd insert queries, even if it fails for 1st one.

Comment: No, it does not. Really. @Rutuja

Comment: I ended up with the solution of adding 'GO' after each sql statement and splitting by it while running the script file in c#, so, I will get the number of affected rows till the exception occurs and rest of the queries will not get execute. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with the solution of adding 'GO' after each sql statement and splitting by it while running the script file in c#, so, I will get the number of affected rows till the exception occurs and rest of the queries will not get execute.